# run javascript of HTML page without to open HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have tried my best to find the solution but failed. I want to run the JavaScript from an HTML page without opening that page. I have uploaded the page to my domain and want to auto update my database user vehicle distance at 12 a.m.

Can anyone help me understand how to run the JavaScript without opening this page?

```
<script>
    setInterval(autoIncrease, 1000*60*3);
    function autoIncrease() {
       var date = new Date();
       var h=date.getHours();
       var m=date.getMinutes();
       if(h==0 && m==0){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url:"http://mobilapps.zicoil.pk/autoUpdate.php",
               async: false,
               crossDomain: true,
               cache: false,
               success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
               }
           });
        }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe you should check about *jsonp* protocol, for cross domain ajax requests.

Comment: Move the code outside of that page? Put it in it's own JavaScript file in your project and then reference it in the page you need to use the code.

Comment: So if I understand right, you have certain function which is to be called automatically at certain time, but you dont want this page to be opened. Question is, is there any other page of your app, open? If yes, move this function to external JS and import it in master template

Comment: no page will be opened i want to run this script to run without any page to open

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you need the HTML to run the code, because the webpage contains the code. Do you mean that you want to run the code without opening the webpage? I do not think that you can do that. You must run code in a console or similar. You must use HTML to use it in a browser. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like you want to periodically (at 12:00 am?) create an HTTP POST request to the server URL mentioned in your snippet. IF that is true the approach you are trying (i.e from javascript embedded in an HTML page) is not the right approach. The easiest solution would be to convert this to a shell script and invoke from a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to run the script without having to open the page in the browser, right?
If Yes, it will not be possible in this way because javascript is interpreted browser side, the interpreters V8, SpriderMonkey, etc ... as we can see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine

There are other ways to do this through languages like node.js that runs on a server your javascript code, you can host your node easily and free in '' Now Project '-> https://zeit.co/now or Heroku -> https://www.heroku.com
in my github I have a basic server in node.js to run on heroku -> https://github.com/navarrojava/heroku_node
in 15 minutes you can solve your problem.
I hope to have helped.

Comment: kindly can you explain how to write javascript or other language code that will call page with url as in question and it will automatically run at night 12 a.m without to run in browser

Comment: You can get my example project on github, copy and paste your code into index.js and deploy on heroku.

Comment: this way will work if you are not yet familiar with node, do not hesitate to start studying because it is very good. I hope to have helped.

Answer (score -2):

https://nodejs.org - Have a lot of extra stuff as well as compiler. But theres no html so you have to use console.log . Ajax would not work. But you could use modules like express or request
jsfiddle.net - Browser based
jsdb .org - standalone console just plain javascript

From what  it sounds like you don't want to open it from the browser. In that case you sound try nodejs. It is based off the v8 javascript engine. Which is used in the chrome browser.

Here is a example on how it would work in nodejs.
Note I changed the interval to every 10 second just for the example
https://runkit.com/5818b2f97f47d000133fa878/5818b2f97f47d000133fa879

Comment: kindly can you explain me from beginning how to create account and upload code